# Password being removed from parameters in my controller despite being allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt

In my KidsController I have

```
def kid_params
  params.require(:kid).permit(:firstname,
                              :lastname,
                              :gender,
                              :pseudo,
                              :birthdate,
                              :avatar,
                              :password,
                              :longitude,
                              :latitude,
                              :parent_id)
end
```

While kid is defined as follow:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

However when I try to POST a json to create a new Kid, I get a *password cannot be blank* error.

The log shows:

> Started POST "/kids" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-12 14:28:34 +0900
>   Processing by KidsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"firstname"=>"testpaw", "lastname"=>"qwdqwd",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "kid"=>{"firstname"=>"testpaw",
>   "lastname"=>"qwdqwd"}}

But once I get to the actual create method, my parameters have been reduced to `{"firstname":"testpaw","lastname":"qwdqwd"}`

What is filtering password from my parameters?
Creating a Kid from rails console works fine...

Comment: can you please use `params.except(:password, :password_confirmation)` and let me know

Comment: when you declare `config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]` It will filter your parameter so it will retun look `"password"=>"[FILTERED]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current setup, the `password` is filtered because it is not part of the `kid` namespace. If it should be part of the `kid` namespace, then you need to change this in your view.

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't makes sense to me... why would the view would have anything to do with a controller action ? 
How to add a new member to the kid namespace ?

Comment: Can you maybe update your question with the view action? The problem is that you are allowing the `password` field only in the `kid` namespace. That's what `params.required(:kid)...` does

Comment: I understand now. It could been seen in the logs: I was posting as JSON like this `{"lastname"="toto","firstname"="tata", "password"="tutu"}` whereas it should looks like `"{"kid"=> {"lastname"="toto","firstname"="tata", "password"="tutu"}}"`